# La lista enlazada no apunta a NULL al final

Tags: c, lista, punteros

tengo un problema con el siguiente programa. Este consiste en agregar elementos a una lista enlazada de manera creciente, es decir, los elementos se irán ordenando en la lista de menor a mayor, siendo el de menor valor la "cabeza" de la lista y el de mayor valor aquél que se encuentra en el último nodo, el cual debería de apuntar a NULL.

El problema está en que, al mandar a llamar a la función mostrarDatosLista, la cual me muestra todos los elementos agregados a la lista, realizando un recorrido a través de cada nodo hasta encontrar el valor NULL, me realiza una impresión infinita de (creo yo) las direcciones de memoria siguientes a las cuales apunta el último nodo, y debido a que no es NULL, estas se imprimen de manera constante.

Por lo tanto, mi duda es, ¿Cómo podría modificar el programa de tal manera que el último nodo de mi lista apuntara a NULL, y de esta manera, pudiera imprimir únicamente los valores agregados a mi lista?

Nota: En la función main agregué una prueba en la que ingreso valores a la función ingresarDatos y posteriormente los muestro de manera explícita, sin utilizar la función mostrarDatos, para verificar que los valores se han guardado en la lista.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct elementos
{
    int dato;
    struct elementos *siguiente;
};

typedef struct elementos Nodo;

void ingresarValor(Nodo **cabeza, int valor);
void mostrarDatosLista(Nodo *cabeza);

int main()
{
    int valor;
    Nodo *primero = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    primero = NULL;


ingresarValor(&primero, 2);
ingresarValor(&primero, 4);
ingresarValor(&primero, 3);
ingresarValor(&primero, -1);
ingresarValor(&primero, 6);

printf("%d\n", primero -> dato);
primero = primero -> siguiente;

printf("%d\n", primero -> dato);
primero = primero -> siguiente;

printf("%d\n", primero -> dato);
primero = primero -> siguiente;

printf("%d\n", primero -> dato);
primero = primero -> siguiente;

printf("%d\n", primero -> dato);
primero = primero -> siguiente;

//mostrarDatosLista(primero);

return 0;
}

void ingresarValor(Nodo **cabeza, int valor)
{
    Nodo *nuevo_Nodo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    nuevo_Nodo -> dato = valor;
    nuevo_Nodo -> siguiente == NULL;

if(*cabeza == NULL)
{
    *cabeza = nuevo_Nodo;
}
else if(nuevo_Nodo -> dato > (*cabeza) -> dato)
{
    Nodo *anterior = *cabeza;
    Nodo *p = *cabeza;

    while(nuevo_Nodo -> dato > p -> dato)
    {
        anterior = p;
        p = p -> siguiente;
    }

       anterior -> siguiente = nuevo_Nodo;
       nuevo_Nodo -> siguiente = p;
    }

    else
    {
      nuevo_Nodo -> siguiente = *cabeza;
      *cabeza = nuevo_Nodo;
    }
}

void mostrarDatosLista(Nodo *cabeza)
{
    while(cabeza != NULL)
    {
        printf("%8d\n", cabeza -> dato);
        cabeza = cabeza -> siguiente;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu programa tiene dos errores. Uno de sintaxis bastante traicionero. El otro de concepto.

#### Error de sintaxis

El error de sintaxis está precisamente cuando intentas asignarle el valor `NULL` a `nuevo_Nodo -> siguiente`, ya que en lugar de una asignación estás haciendo una comparación. Fíjate en tu código:

```
Nodo *nuevo_Nodo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
nuevo_Nodo -> dato = valor;
nuevo_Nodo -> siguiente == NULL;
```

El `==` debería ser un solo `=`. El compilador no te ha dado error en esa línea porque sintácticamente es válido, si bien no hace lo que quieres. Simplemente es una expresión cuyo resultado es un booleano que después no asignas a ninguna otra variable. El C permite que una línea sea una expresión sin más, y que su resultado no se asigne a ningún sitio. Es equivalente a tener en un programa una línea que diga:

```
3*(2+2);
```

Este tipo de errores se pueden "pillar" a tiempo si compilas con la opción `-Wall` (asumo que usas `gcc`, sino mira en tu compilador cuál es la opción equivalente para *mostrar todos los niveles de warning*).

De hecho, así fue como descubrí este error, pues traté de compilar tu código con ese flag y me saltó:

```
ej.c: In function ‘ingresarValor’:
ej.c:52:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     nuevo_Nodo -> siguiente == NULL;
```

#### Error de concepto

Una vez arreglado ese error, al ejecutar el programa me dio inmediatamente un *segmentation fault*, que significa que en algún momento intentas desreferenciar un puntero nulo. Compilando con opción de depuración (`-g`) y ejecutándo el programa con `gdb`, descubro que la línea que da el segfault es la que señalo en el código siguiente, de la función `ingresarValor()`:

```
Nodo *anterior = *cabeza;
Nodo *p = *cabeza;

while(nuevo_Nodo -> dato > p -> dato) // <------ AQUI ROMPE
{
    anterior = p;
    p = p -> siguiente;
}
```

En este caso es un error en la lógica del programa ya que lo que pretendes es buscar el elemento de la lista delante del cual hay que insertar el nuevo valor, pero... ¿qué ocurre si llegas al final de la lista? En ese caso `p = p->siguiente` almacenará `NULL` en `p` y cuando la condición del while intente mirar `p->dato`, se producirá el acceso a una dirección de memoria nula que causa el segfault.

La condición del while debe verificar también que `p` no sea `NULL`. La forma más sucinta de lograrlo es cambiarlo así:

```
while(p && nuevo_Nodo -> dato > p -> dato)
{
    anterior = p;
    p = p -> siguiente;
}
```

La condicón `p` es "cierta" si `p` no es `NULL`, y en ese caso continuará verificando lo que hay tras del `&&`. Si `p` es `NULL`, ya no mirará lo que hay tras el `&&` porque de todas formas la expresión será falsa, y así saldrá del bucle.

Con ese cambio he verificado que el programa funciona ahora correctamente.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Lo entendí perfectamente. Efectivamente, utlizó gcc y lo ejecuto en la consola. Ya realicé las correcciones que mencionas y el resultado es el esperado.  ;)